# What does this android wifi error mean?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to configure a network and connect to it using `WifiManager` (from inside a service that I start from my activity's `OnCreate`). I get the following error:

`E/wpa_supplicant﹕ ioctl[SIOCSIWPRIV] (pnosetup): -1`

What exactly is this error?

Enabled permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: A custom IO control command failed?

Comment: Well, sure, but I can't do much with that information. What is SIOCSIWPRIV and pnosetup?

Comment: I would check the privileges of your app and what you need in order to use the `WifiManager` and such. That comes from basic troubleshooting and assuming the 'PRIV' could stand for "privileges".

Comment: Are you able to find what line is causing this error? Might help to know what step your service is at that gets the exception thrown.

Comment: Sadly, I get this error sometime (asyncronously) after I issue WifiManager.enableNetwork call